# I need to dynamically update the date based on the current year. Currently hardcoded in html. Need to update a single word

Tags: javascript, html, date

```
<h1>Hello<span id="currentyear">(Welcome to your 2015 Shopping Spree)</span></h1>
```

That's the HTML I have, I need to just update the 2015 bit.

```
function fullYear() {
var today = new Date();
var currentYear = document.getElementById("currentyear");

currentYear = currentYear.outerHTML;
currentYear = currentYear.match(/2015/g);
currentYear = JSON.parse(currentYear);
currentYear = today.getFullYear();
```

}

fullYear();

That's the JS, I'm fairly new at this, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you need to assign back to the outerHTML. Personally I would use innerText.

Comment: Why even try and update just the year? Make it easy and just re-write the whole string with the correct year.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to wrap the year in a tag so you don't have to search/regex for it:

```
<h1>Hello<span id="currentyear">(Welcome to your <span id="year">2015</span> Shopping Spree)</span></h1>

function fullYear(){
    document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
var currentyear = document.getElementById('currentyear');
currentyear.textContent = currentyear.textContent.replace(/\d{4}/, new Date().getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the year in an element which you can get with JS.

**HTML Code:**

```
<h1>Hello<span id="currentyear">(Welcome to your <span id="fullYear">2015</span> Shopping Spree)</span></h1>
```

**JS Code:**

```
function setFullYear () {
    var fullYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('fullYear').textContent = fullYear.toString();
}

setFullYear();
```

If you don't want to add a new tag for it, but using replace instead, do like this:

**JS Code:**

```
function setFullYear () {
    var fullYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var currentYearSpan = document.getElementById('currentyear');
    var originText = currentYearSpan.textContent;
    currentYearSpan.textContent = originText.replace('2015', fullYear.toString());
}

setFullYear();
```

Try to make it simple, you don't need regex replace here.